# Django Rest Framework TypeError at / __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'read_only'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This super helpful error "ATypeError at /
**init**() got multiple values for keyword argument 'read_only'" is occurring with the following serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField('posts', lookup_field='username', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'posts', )


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False,  read_only=True)
    photos = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField('photos', read_only=True)
    # author = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', lookup_field='username')

    def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Need to exclude `user` since we'll add that later based off the request
        exclusions = super(PostSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions(*args, **kwargs)
        return exclusions + ['author']

    class Meta:
        model = Post


class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.Field('image.url' , read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `HyperlinkedIdentityField` is **always read-only**, that is why it doesn't support read_only argument. Allowed arguments:

- view_name
- lookup_field
- lookup_url_kwarg
- format